# Storing linked list heads in a 2D array

Tags: arrays, pointers, struct, linked-list, malloc

I need to create a 2D matrix of dynamic size where each element of the matrix will contain a pointer to the head of a linked list. The code I used for defining a head is the following:

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
struct Node *head = NULL;
head = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 
head->data = 1;
head->next = NULL;
```

Then I used the following code to create the array:

```
struct Node **array = (struct Node **)malloc(Nx * Ny * sizeof(struct Node *));
for(i = 0; i < Nx*Ny; i++)
    array[i] = head;
```

But I am getting segmentation fault.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are `Nx` and `Ny`'s values?

Comment: They are quite large. ~50,000